# How to send variable on submit() using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

This is the code I have:

```
 var IsWithHistory = 1;
 if (stat == 'P') {
    var ans = confirm("Copy product with selection History");
    if (ans == true) {
        $("#CopyProductHeaderForm").submit();
    } else {
        IsWithHistory = 0;
        $("#CopyProductHeaderForm").submit();
    }
 }
```

CopyProductHeaderForm is going to my controller with this Can I send IsWithHistroy Value to the controller? how to send this value to the controller to check the condition.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You include a hidden field inside this form:

```
<%= Html.Hidden("IsWithHistory") %>
```

and then you set its value before submitting:

```
$('#IsWithHistory').val(IsWithHistory);
$('#CopyProductHeaderForm').submit();
```

Now the controller will get the `IsWithHistory` value.

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden field to the form and manipulate that before submitting.

Example:

```
<form id="CopyProductHeaderForm">
...
<input type="hidden" id="IsWithHistory" value="1"/>
...
</form>

<script>
  if (stat == 'P') {
    if (!confirm("Copy product with selection History")) {
      $("#IsWithHistory").val(0);
    }
    $("#CopyProductHeaderForm").submit();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden input field to your form (either in HTML or using Javascript) and set the value of that hidden input field to IsWithHistory.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to create an input in your form, say a hidden one here. Set its name to `IsWithHistory` and set it's value to your javascript var.

Then in your controller action add a parameter `int IsWithHistory`.